# How to flatten/split a tuple of arrays and calculate column means in Polars dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]), ([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 7, 9])]}
)
```

Basically, each cell of `a` is a tuple of three arrays of the same length. I want to fully split them to separate columns (one scalar resides in one column) like the shape below:

```
shape: (2, 9)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ field_0 ┆ field_1 ┆ field_2 ┆ field_3 ┆ ... ┆ field_5 ┆ field_6 ┆ field_7 ┆ field_8 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 2       ┆ ... ┆ 4       ┆ 6       ┆ 7       ┆ 8       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 3       ┆ ... ┆ 5       ┆ 5       ┆ 7       ┆ 9       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

One way I have tried is to use `arr.to_struct` and `unnest` two times to fully flatten the two nested levels. Two levels is fine here, but if there are a variety of nested levels and the number could not be determined ahead, the code will be so long.

Is there any simpler (or more systematic) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking on some of the concepts in the other answers...

We can see how much nesting there is by checking the `inner` datatype of the [pl.List](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.List.html) datatype for the column. This can be the condition for a loop. Here's an example with one further nesting of lists than the initial question:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]], [[2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8]], [[6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 16]]), ([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]], [[3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10]], [[5, 10], [7, 14], [9, 18]])]})

shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                   │
│ ---                                 │
│ list[list[list[i64]]]               │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]], [[2, ... │
│ [[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]], [[3, ... │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

```
expr = pl.col('a')
dtype = df.schema['a']

# alternative: dtype.base_type() == pl.List
while isinstance(dtype.inner, pl.List):
    expr = expr.arr.eval(pl.element().arr.explode())
    dtype = dtype.inner

df.lazy().select(expr.arr.to_struct()).collect().unnest('a')
```

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ field_0 ┆ field_1 ┆ field_2 ┆ field_3 ┆ ... ┆ field_14 ┆ field_15 ┆ field_16 ┆ field_17 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆     ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆     ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64      ┆ i64      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ 4       ┆ ... ┆ 7        ┆ 14       ┆ 8        ┆ 16       │
│ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 2       ┆ 4       ┆ ... ┆ 7        ┆ 14       ┆ 9        ┆ 18       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: If I tried your code on a lazy df returned from calculations, there is an error - pyo3_runtime.PanicException: not implemented for dtype Unknown. Does it mean it cannot be used on a lazy dataframe returned from calculations?

Comment: Have a slightly different problem for lazy df here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631703/follow-up-how-to-return-multiple-stats-as-multiple-columns-in-polars-grouby-con>

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a good idea, but I used `_string_repr()` and counted how many times `list` appears in the schema and flatten that many times - 1 (and do a reshape at the end to retain the original number of rows). This also works with more highly nested lists.

```py
def append_arr_explode(expr: pl.Expr, n: int) -> pl.Expr:
    for _ in range(n):
        expr = expr.arr.explode()
    return expr

print(
    df.lazy()
    .select(
        pl.col("a")
        .pipe(append_arr_explode, df.schema["a"]._string_repr().count("list") - 1)
        .reshape((df.height, -1))
        .arr.to_struct()
    )
    .unnest("a")
    .collect()
)
```

Comment: this solution works great on regular dataframe, but it fails to work on lazy dataframe.

Comment: Have a slightly different problem for lazy df here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631703/follow-up-how-to-return-multiple-stats-as-multiple-columns-in-polars-grouby-con>

Answer (score 1):

Here some solution. You can use pipe: `.arr.explode().arr.explode().[...]` till you unpack all levels of nested list.

```py
                                   #  add more of these exprs according
df.select(                         #  to the number of nested lists (n-1)
    pl.col("a").arr.eval(          #  /
        pl.element().arr.explode() # .arr.explode() ...
    ).arr.get(i).alias(f"field_{i}") for i in range(9)
)
```

Comment: Have a slightly different problem for lazy df here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75631703/follow-up-how-to-return-multiple-stats-as-multiple-columns-in-polars-grouby-con>